# how to update value of double after updating jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double, defaulttablemodel

[image]I need some help with updating value of double after i update the JTable, the code should get values from column and put them together.

here is the code to get value :

```
double cpusum = 0;
int prow=1;

DefaultTableModel cpuprice = (DefaultTableModel) cpubaskettable.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < cpuprice.getRowCount(); i++) {
    cpusum = cpusum + Double.parseDouble(cpuprice.getValueAt(prow, 5).toString());

}
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");





JLabel cpubaskettotallabel = new JLabel("Total Price: " + df.format(cpusum));
```

And here is the code for updating of JTable:

```
private void cputobasket(){
    TableModel model1 = cputablebottom.getModel();
    int [] index = cputablebottom.getSelectedRows();
    Object []row = new Object[6];
    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) cpubaskettable.getModel();
    for (int i = 0; i<index.length;i++){
        row[0] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 0);
        row[1] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 1);
        row[2] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 2);
        row[3] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 3);
        row[4] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 4);
        row[5] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 5);
        model2.addRow(row);
    }

}
```

And it also should update when a row is deleted, the code:

```
private void deletecpufrombasket(){

    int row = cpubaskettable.getSelectedRow();
    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) cpubaskettable.getModel();

        model2.removeRow(row);
    }
```

Comment: So, based on what I understand, you want to update a label based on total of a given column?  Start by having a look at [`TableModelListener`'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html) and [How to Write a Table Model Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html) which will provide with notification when the model is changed

Comment: the tablemodellistener seems good, ill take a look on it, haven't seen it before, thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: Swing makes use the observer pattern quite extensively, in most cases, there's typically some listener or event notification occurring for most things